# ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services.db: 'enviroment'

Tags: docker-compose

version: '3.8'
services:
 db:
  image: mysql
  command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
  restart: always
  enviroment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: redhat

adminer:
  image: adminer
  restart: always
  depends_on:
   - db
  ports:
   - "8040:8040"

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled `environment`